# Trouble compressing large files using vbs

Tags: windows, vbscript, compression

I have jumbled up a vbs script to compress files older than 7 days using 7za's command line utility. While most of the logic works fine, I am able to compress single file into single zip file.

The problem arises when I try to add all matching files to one zip file. Below is the code snippet:

```
strCommand = "7za.exe -mx=9 a " & ObjectFolder & sysDate & ".zip " & strFileName
strRun = objShell.Run(strCommand, 0, True)
```

Now as per the 2<sup>nd</sup> line, setting `True` would make sure the script will wait till command is finished executing. But the problem is `7za` is exiting immediately and going to the next loop, processing the next file and since it tries to create same zip file, I get access denied error.

Can someone please help me to fix this?

I have also tested the scenario in command prompt. What I did was, execute below 2 commands simultaneously in separate prompts:

Prompt 1:
    C:\7za.exe -mx=9 a test.zip c:\sample1.pdf

Prompt 2:
    C:\7za.exe -mx=9 a test.zip c:\sample2.pdf

Prompt 2 resulted in following error:

> Error: test.zip is not supported archive
>   System error:
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

This is the same error I am getting in my script and I need help in resolving this. Any pointers will be helpful!

**UPDATE:**

With the great pointers provided by both John and Ansgar, I was able to resolve this! It turned out to be a bug in my script! In my script, I included a check to see if the file is in use by any other process before processing it for archive. So I was checking this by opening the file for appending using:

```
Set f = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForAppending, True)
```

But before proceeding to process the same file, I was not CLOSING it in the script, hence the error: ***The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process***

After I closed the file, all went well!

Thanks Again for all the great support I got here!

As a token of gratitude, I am sharing the whole script for anyone's use. Please note that I am not the original author of this, I gathered it from various sources and tweaked it a little bit to suit my needs.

## **Archive.vbs**

```
Const ForAppending = 8  ' Constant for file lock check

Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFiles, objShell
Dim file, fileExt, fileName, strCommand, strRun, strFile
Dim SFolder, OFolder, Extension, DaysOld, sDate

'''' SET THESE VARIABLES! ''''
SFolder = "C:\SourceFolder\"      'Folder to look in
OFolder = "C:\OutputFolder\"      'Folder to put archives in
Extension = "pdf"        'Extension of files you want to zip
DaysOld = 1        'Zip files older than this many days
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

sDate = DatePart("yyyy",Date) & "-" & Right("0" & DatePart("m",Date), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & DatePart("d",Date), 2)


'Create object for playing with files
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Create shell object for running commands
Set objShell = wscript.createObject("wscript.shell")

'Set folder to look in
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(SFolder)

'Get files in folder
Set objFiles = objFolder.Files

'Loop through the files
For Each file in objFiles
  fileName = Split(file.Name, ".")
  fileExt = fileName(UBound(fileName))
  'See if it is the type of file we are looking for
  If fileExt = Extension Then
    'See if the file is older than the days chosen above
    If DateDiff("d", file.DateLastModified, Now()) >= DaysOld Then
      strFile = file.Path
      'See if the file is available or in use
        Set f = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForAppending, True)
        If Err.Number = 70 Then ' i.e. if file is locked

        Else
        f.close
        strFName = objFSO.GetBaseName(file.name)
        strCommand = "C:\7za.exe -mx=9 a " & OFolder & sDate & ".zip " & strFile

        strRun = objShell.Run(strCommand, 0, True)
        'wscript.echo strCommand  ' un-comment this to check the file(s) being processed
        'file.Delete  ' un-comment this to delete the files after compressing.
        End If
    End If

  End If
Next

'Cleanup
Set objFiles = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
wscript.Quit
```

===========================

Thanks

-Noman A.

Comment: Forgot to add this, If anyone wants to use this vbs script to compress files into individual zips [Example: sample.pdf --> sample.zip], just changed the strCommand to [ strCommand = "C:\7za.exe -mx=9 a " & OFolder & strFName & ".zip " & strFile" ]
where strFName = actual file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you asked for, but here's a batch script I use for a similar task in case that helps get you past of your immediate issue:

ArchiveScriptLog.Bat

```
::ensure we're in the right directory, then run the script & log the output
cls
pushd "c:\backup scripts"
ArchiveScript.bat > ArchiveScript.log
popd
```

ArchiveScript.bat

```
::Paths (must include the \ on the end).  There must be no space between the equals and the value
::UNC paths are acceptable

Set FolderToBackup=F:\EnterpriseArchitect\Energy\
Set BackupPath=F:\EnterpriseArchitect\!ARCHIVE\
Set RemoteBackupPath=\\ukccojdep01wok\h$\Energy\cciobis01edc\
Set SevenZip=C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\

::Get DATE in yyyymmdd format; done in two lines to make it easy to change the date format
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3,4 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %Date%') DO (SET mm=%%A&SET dd=%%B&SET yyyy=%%C)
SET strDate=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%

::Set the Backup File to be the backup path with the current date & .zip on the end
Set BackupFile=%BackupPath%%strDate%.zip

::create a zip containing the contents of folderToBackup
pushd %SevenZip%
7z a "%BackupFile%" "%FolderToBackup%"
popd

::go to the archive directory & copy all files in there to the remote location (this accounts for previous errors if the network were unavailable)
pushd "%BackupPath%"
move *.zip "%RemoteBackupPath%"
popd

::delete off backups in the remote location which are older than 90 days
pushd "%RemoteBackupPath%"
forfiles /D -90 /M *.zip /C "cmd /c del @file"
popd
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the script John, its really neat and I might use it in some other scenario in the future. My scenario is, there is a folder in client's server with pdfs generated in it on a daily basis. What I am trying to do is schedule a script that would look into this folder and archive all pdf's older than a week and then delete those pdfs. As I mentioned, my only problem is when I am trying to put them in one zip file. 
Your contribution is much appreciated! The reason I love this communtity!
-Noman A.

Comment: No worries - just found this which may help: http://www.naterice.com/articles/38.  I have to drop offline now, but if you're still having problems after 24 hours give me a nudge and I'll have a play with vbs over the weekend.

Comment: That's superb John, let me give it a look, and I'll keep you posted. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: John, I am accepting your answer as it offers an alternate option to what I intend to do and could be very helpful for others. Thanks again for your contribution and help.

Answer (score 1):

Your command shouldn't return before `7za` has finished its task (and it doesn't in my tests). Try changing your code to the following, so you can see what's going on:

```
strCommand = "7za.exe -mx=9 a " & ObjectFolder & sysDate & ".zip " & strFileName
strCommand = "%COMSPEC% /k " & strCommand
strRun = objShell.Run(strCommand, 1, True)
```

It may also be a good idea to quote the filenames:

```
Function qq(str)
  qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function

strCommand = "7za.exe -mx=9 a " & qq(ObjectFolder & sysDate & ".zip") & " " _
  & qq(strFileName)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Ansgar, I had already tried the "%COMSPEC" method, from there only I was able to identify the actual error:
"System error:
  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
But still I will incorporate both the changed and see if I can get past this deamon :)

Thanks Again!
-Noman A.